# Replacing column value interchangeably using a condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, tidyverse

In the R data frame coded for below, I would like to interexchange "Amount1" column with "Amount2" column value if "Dupl" column has 8 in row.

- Input dataframe

```
dt <- data.table(ID=c("A","A","B","B"),Amount1=c(100,200,300,400), Amount2=c(1500,1500,2400,2400),Dupl=c(1,8,1,0))
```

Now since "Dupl" column have 8 is second row so I want to change "Amount1" with "Amount2" in second row.

- Desired Output

```
dt <- data.table(ID=c("A","A","B","B"),Amount1=c(100,1500,300,400), Amount2=c(1500,200,2400,2400),Dupl=c(1,8,1,0))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `base R`, this can be done with row column indexing i.e. use the logical condition for row, and reverse the column names in the `lhs` and `rhs` of the `<-`

```
dt[Dupl == 8, c("Amount1", "Amount2")] <- dt[Dupl == 8, c("Amount2", "Amount1")]
```

NOTE: `Dupl ==  8` works only because the object is `data.table`.  If it is a `data.frame` alone, use `dt$Dupl == 8`

-output

```
> dt
   ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
1:  A     100    1500    1
2:  A    1500     200    8
3:  B     300    2400    1
4:  B     400    2400    0
```

---

Or the same approach in `data.table` i.e. specify the `i` with logical condition, specify the `.SDcols` in reverse order, assign (`:=`) the Subset of data.table (`.SD`) in correct order

```
dt[Dupl == 8, c("Amount1", "Amount2") := .SD, .SDcols = c("Amount2", "Amount1")]
```

Comment: Thank you, dear, it is working. Faced some problem in real data but get over the problem from here.  https://community.rstudio.com/t/creating-columns-with-data-table-within-a-function/76377

Answer (score 0):

[akrun's second approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68929104/3817004) can be further streamlined by

```
cols <- c("Amount1", "Amount2")
dt[Dupl == 8, (cols) := .SD, .SDcols = rev(cols)][]
```

or, alternatively,

```
cols <- c("Amount1", "Amount2")
dt[Dupl == 8, rev(cols) := .SD, .SDcols = cols][]
```

Both return

> ```
>    ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
> 1:  A     100    1500    1
> 2:  A    1500     200    8
> 3:  B     300    2400    1
> 4:  B     400    2400    0
> ```

Or, avoiding the `.SDcols` parameter:

```
dt[Dupl == 8, `:=`(Amount1 = Amount2, Amount2 = Amount1)][]
```

---

I have also tried approaches with `fifelse()` but these are quite verbose because `fifelse()` can only deal with vector values, e.g.,

```
dt[, c("Amount1", "Amount2") := .(fifelse(Dupl == 8, Amount2, Amount1), 
                                  fifelse(Dupl == 8, Amount1, Amount2))][]
```

or

```
dt[, `:=`(Amount1 = fifelse(Dupl == 8, Amount2, Amount1), 
          Amount2 = fifelse(Dupl == 8, Amount1, Amount2))][]
```

Comment: @gupta, unfortunately, all your upvotes were removed by SO :-( I was told "When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them."

Comment: Yeah dear, I got the same message, I think moderator read every single message since the warning came after almost 1 hr. I will keep it in mind and try to visit your account regularly for learning purposes. Thanks